# Eyelids twitching when applying makeup!

Tags: makeup

So I have this weird issue of twitchy and watery eyes when someone is applying makeup especially eyeliner on my eyes. My eyes start blinking and twitching to the point that it becomes almost impossible to apply makeup on my eyes (although everyone says heavy eye makeup suits me!). My wedding function is coming up in a few months and I have booked a very good makeup artist but I am extremely worried about this problem of mine. Any tips in overcoming this issue?

P.S: I don't have this issue when I myself am applying makeup on my own eyes!

Answer (score 2):

Ask the makeup artist that you booked. I'm sure they have encountered people with a similar reaction, and they'll probably have some suggestions for you.

Comment: Tbh I am actually ashamed and afraid of asking, so far I haven't met anyone like me so I feel kind of weird of even saying this!

Comment: I'm sure your makeup artist has heard everything! They've put makeup on a lot of people. There are probably people with fears of makeup or reactions that you haven't even heard of. Plus, when you tell your makeup artist, it will let them know what to expect so it will make their job easier!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help , I will keep your advice in mind :)